# String iteration c# mono

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, mono

I have string of length 2418060 chars.
This string contains numbers, bracets and some special symbols. It's a sample

```
!(242.9288)F(562.7884)/(45)!(242.9288)F(126.8685)&(18.95)F(126.8685)!(140.2591)F(114.399)&
```

It's LindermayerSystem so every char have spacial action and the number in bracet it's is variables.

How can I fast iterate throu this? When I'm iterating char by char by simple for loop it last 10 minutes and Unity isn't responding after this.. of course inside I have switch :

```
switch (array[i])
             {
                 //TurnLeft
                 case '+':
                     i+=2;
                     do
                     {
                         checkingString.Append(array[i]);
                         i++;
                     } while (array[i] != ')');

                     value=float.Parse(checkingString.ToString());

                     currentPosRot.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(value, Vector3.left) * currentPosRot.rotation;

                    //position = position + (rotation * new Vector3(0, 2, 0));

                    //curve.AddPointAt(position);


                    checkingString = new StringBuilder();

                     value = 0.0f;
                     break;
                 //Turn right
                 case '-': ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an optimization problem. I would assume that in this specific case the second rule of optimization would apply: Don't optimize yet.

Step 1: Cut your input data (the 2 MB string) down to a reasonably well testable size. Make it so that you are able to attach the Unity profiler and still get the performance results in less than 10 seconds.

Step 2: Profile. See where exactly the processing time goes.

Step 3: Pick the top 1 time consumer and improve it so that it takes less processing power. Then start over from step 2, until your performance problem is solved.